# Using relative path for fstream on Mac using Sublime Text 2

Tags: c++, macos, sublimetext2

Ok, so my code is pretty simple.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char a; char mas[5000];
    fstream fin;
    fin.open("input.txt", ios::in);
    if(!fin.is_open()) cout << "No file found!";
    getcwd(mas, 5000);
    cout << mas;
    return 0;
}
```

So My input file is next to cpp file and next to built executable file, but The error message is displayed. So I checked with getcwd function where is the actual workplace, because even with full path it didn't work, and my files are on desktop (/Users/user/Desktop), but getcwd showed me - /Users/user, so I was confused but tried to put my txt file there and it worked, how can I change that method "open" opens file with relative path that is actually next top cpp or executable file?

Answer (score 0):

The `argv` parameter of `main()` is the command line used to invoke the executable, so you can use `argv[0]` to get the path of the executable in order to build the path to your input file:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char **argv){
    char a; char mas[5000];
    fstream fin;

    string dirname, inputFilename;
    const char *p = strrchr(argv[0], '/');
    if (p != 0)
        dirname = string(argv[0], p - argv[0] + 1);
    inputFilename = dirname + "input.txt";

    fin.open(inputFilename.c_str(), ios::in);
    if(!fin.is_open()) {
        cout << "No file found!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    getcwd(mas, 5000);
    cout << mas << endl;
    return 0;
}
```